# Problemas em formatar o tipo de data retornado do select

Tags: php, mysql, data

Bom dia
Gostaria que vocês me ajudassem com um pequeno problema que estou tento no meu retorno de um select em php.
Eu gostaria que o retorno do meu "Mes_Ref", do meu select fosse apenas mes e ano sem o dia e o ano fosse reduzido. exemplo esse e meu retorno atual `[{"Mes_Ref":"2016-04-01"}]`   e eu Gostaria que o retorno fosse esse `[{"Mes_Ref":"04/16"}]`. ou `[{"Mes_Ref":"04-16"}]` tanto faz. 
segue meu codigo abaixo

```
<?php
//-------------------------------------------Demanda--------------------------------------------------///////

mysql_connect('blablabla','uaaa','lll');
mysql_select_db('aaaa') or die (mysql_error());



$Cod_Empresa = $_GET['aaaa'];
$aa = $_GET['aaa'];
$aa = $_GET['aaa'];
$aa = $_GET['aaaa'];
$tensao  = strtoupper($_GET['aa']);

if (($di != "") && ($df != ""))
    {
        $periodo = '
        && D.Mes_Ref >= "'.$aa.'"
        && D.Mes_Ref <= "'.$aa.'"
            Order By Mes_Ref DESC
                ';
    }
else
    {
        $periodo = '
            Order By Mes_Ref DESC
            Limit 0,12
                ';
    }
switch($tensao)
    {
        case 'BT':
            $tensao_ = "";
            break;
        case 'AT':
            $tensao_ = "
                && D.Tip_Fatur = 0
                && D.Classe in ('A1','A2','A3','A3a')
            ";
            break;
        case 'MT':
            $tensao_ = "
                && D.Tip_Fatur = 0
                && D.Classe in ('A4','As')
            ";
            break;
        case 'ML':
            $tensao_ = "
                && D.Tip_Fatur = 1
            ";
            break;
    }   

switch($tensao)
{
    case 'BT':
            $sql = "Select Mes_Ref,
                        round(KW_P_Reg,0) as KWP ,
                        round (KW_FP_Ind_Reg,0) as KWPFP 
                From Tab_Fatura_BT D
                WHERE Cod_Empresa = ".$Cod_Empresa."
                && Cod_UC = ".$aa."
                ".$tensao_."
                ".$periodo."
                    ";
            break;                      
        default:
                $sql = "SELECT D.Mes_Ref,
                            round(D.Contr_KW_P,0) as Contr_KW_P , 
                            round(D.Contr_KW_FP,0) as Contr_KW_FP,
                            round(L.KW_P_res + L.KW_P_per,0)as KWP , 
                            round((L.KW_FP_res + L.KW_FP_per),0)as KWPFP 
                    FROM Tab_Fatura_Dados D, Tab_Fatura_Leituras L
                WHERE D.Cod_Empresa = ".$Cod_Empresa."
                && D.Cod_UC = ".$aa."
                && L.Cod_Empresa = D.Cod_Empresa
                && L.Cod_UC = D.Cod_UC
                && L.Cod_Fatura = D.Cod_Fatura
                ".$tensao_."
                ".$periodo."
            ";
            break;
}


    $query = mysql_query( $sql ) or die('Could not query');                             


    for($rows = array(); $row = mysql_fetch_object($query); $rows[] = $row);
            {       
                echo json_encode($rows);    
            } 

?>
```

a figura abaixo mostra o retorno do select
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Vejam que ele imprimi pra mim os ultimos 12 meses do usuario  e eu gostaria que continuasse assim porem  como eu disse no começo  no lugar de [{"Mes_Ref":"2016-04-01"}]   e eu Gostaria que o retorno fosse esse [{"Mes_Ref":"04/16"}]. ou [{"Mes_Ref":"04-16"}] tanto faz.
Obs; Eu usei o date.formate  e ele gerou erro no retorno  ao inves de exibir os ultimos meses ele exibiu  assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

reparem que os valores não são iguais  pq de alguma forma o date.formate me retornou apenas o mes "12" de cada ano  o que para mim não serve 
sera que alguem pode me ajudar..
agradeço

Comment: É melhor colocar texto do que imagens

Comment: Ola, na base dados qual é o tipo da coluna Mes_Ref?

Comment: acredito que seja tipo date .. eu não tenho acesso ao banco de dados, sou novo na empresa, quem tem  esse acesso e o outro programador

Comment: e @WallaceMaxters eu coloquei toda a minha programação ai e o resultado   esta tudo ai..

Comment: alguem sabe me dizer o porque que o date.format esta retornando os mes "12" de cada ano...  ao inves de me retornar os ultimos 12 meses  como deveria

Comment: Pessoal  basta mudar o apelido de Mes_Ref para qq outro  no meu caso mudei pra Data    que deu certo... de alguma forma usar o mesmo nome dava erro   só não sei explicar pq

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pessoal consegui  arrumar como eu queria  basta fazer da seguinte maneira

$sql = "SELECT REPLACE(date_format(D.Mes_Ref,'%m-%y') , '-', '/' ) as Data,

essa forma de fazer recebe o D.Mes_Ref exemplo (19/05/2016) do banco  e modifica para   (05/2016) ou seja só fica  com mes e ano.
obrigado galera

Answer (score 2):

tente utilizar a função date format do mysql

```
select date_format(D.Mes_Ref,'%m/%Y')
```

Comment: Não vou negativar, mas formatar dados a partir de do banco de dados é uma péssima prática.

Comment: o problema e que isso me retorna um json_encode  para o aplicativo android e la e mais dficil formatar os dados

Comment: alguem sabe me dizer o porque que o date.format esta retornando os mes "12" de cada ano... ao inves de me retornar os ultimos 12 meses como deveria

Comment: @ThiagoLunardi Por que é uma péssima prática?

Comment: @WallaceMaxters, pois não é responsabilidade do banco em formatar dados, isso é responsabilidade da aplicação. Banco deve ser usado apenas, e somente apenas, para persistir e recuperar dados da maneira mais rápida possível. E formatar dados, consome recurso com ações que não função de um banco de dados.

Comment: @Tiago, basta formatar no lado da aplicação - backend - e não no banco de dados.

Comment: Pessoal basta mudar o apelido de Mes_Ref para qq outro no meu caso mudei pra Data que deu certo... de alguma forma usar o mesmo nome dava erro só não sei explicar pq –

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar a função date para armazenar a data formatada antes de retornar o json_encode.

Ex:

```
$retorno = [];

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query));
      {       
          $row['Mes_Ref'] = date('m/Y',strtotime($row['Mes_Ref']));
          $retorno = $row;

      }

 return json_encode($retorno);
```

Comment: não da para fazer isso pq quando do echo pra exibir  eu preciso retornar em formato json_encode  pq essa informação vai para  o aplicativo android

Comment: @Tiago, você pode utilizar a função date para armazenar a data formatada no indice do array antes de retornar o json_encode. Ex: $row['Mes_Ref'] = date('m/Y',strtotime($row['Mes_Ref']));

Comment: Desculpe não intendi direito aonde eu colocaria esse exemplo seu no meu codigo

Comment: ainda não deu certo

Comment: alguem sabe me dizer o porque que o date.format esta retornando os mes "12" de cada ano... ao inves de me retornar os ultimos 12 meses como deveria

Comment: ja consegui   
Pessoal basta mudar o apelido de Mes_Ref para qq outro no meu caso mudei pra Data que deu certo... de alguma forma usar o mesmo nome dava erro só não sei explicar pq –

Answer (score 1):

Não pode usar o mesmo nome `D.Mes_Ref`  com o apelido :

`$sql = "SELECT REPLACE(date_format(D.Mes_Ref,'%m-%y') , '-', '/' ) Mes_Ref`,

Altere o apelido para qualquer outro